# C++ 3 for loops, results should not be repeated

Tags: c++

I've been doing one program:

> When a user enters number N, write down all A,B,C number if A*B*C=N in form "A*B*C". Same A,B,C numbers in different order should not be repeated.

Here's my code, but it's still duplicating it because I haven't done anything about it yet. I had an idea about 2D arrays, but then I remembered they can not change their size.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    int N,A,B,C;

    cin>>N;

    for(A=1;A<=N;A++){
        for(int B=1;B<=N;B++){
            for(int C=1;C<=N;C++){
                if(A*B*C==N)
                    cout<<A<<"*"<<B<<"*"<<C<<endl;      
            }
        }

    }   

    return 0;
}
```

Is there any idea to do it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (`g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...), then [**use the `gdb` debugger**](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/)

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a *fix-my-code* or *do-my-homework* service. You need to learn programming. It takes [time](http://norvig.com/21-days.html)

Comment: @Basile, OP does not appear to be asking us to do the work, specifically "Is there any *idea* to do it?".  Asking for *guidance* with homework is, I believe, perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Notice also that last loop is unneeded: `C` would be `N / (A * B)` when valid (so when `N % (A * B) == 0`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ensure that you get no reordered results simply by making sure that `A <= B <= C`.

And the *way* you can do that is<sup>(a)</sup>:

```
for a = 1 to N inclusive:
    for b = a to N inclusive:
        for c = b to N inclusive:
            checkIf (a * b * c == N)
```

For example, with `N == 6`, you'll get:

```
1 1 6
1 2 3
```

and nothing else.

Keep in mind that, if the numbers need to be *unique,*, just use (e.g.):

```
for b = a + 1 to N inclusive
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Pseudo-code, since the probability that this is class work is *very* close to one, and you should be doing *some* of the work :-)

Answer (score 1):

One way to avoid duplicating output (without keeping a list of all previously generated triples) is to keep the invariant `A <= B <= C` (i.e. only produce sorted triples as output).

As for how to program it: That's left as an exercise for the reader. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have to visualize that in below three loops you are using the same number again and again. For example:

```
Let you have N = 5,
Now when A = 1 then you get B = 1 and C = 5 and also you will get B = 5 and C = 1.
```

So you have to initialize A, B, C in for loop in such a manner that the values will not be repeated.

Below is the corrected code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    int N,A,B,C;

    cin>>N;

    for(A=1;A<=N;A++){
        for(int B=A;B<=N;B++){
            for(int C=B;C<=N;C++){
                if(A*B*C==N)
                    cout<<A<<"*"<<B<<"*"<<C<<endl;      
            }
        }

    }   

    return 0;
}
```